# Self Study Probability Question, Correct Solution?

Tags: probability, self-learning

Question: On average 15% of the population have negative side effects on a particular drug A. 21 patients are chosen randomly. What is the probability that at least 2 of them have negative side effects.

Solution: Let $X$ be the number of patients who have negative side effects, then $X \sim Bin(n,p)$. Furthermore we know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = np = 0.15 \Rightarrow p = \frac{0.15}{n}$ Here $n=21$ thus: $p = \frac{0.15}{21}$. The probability that at least 2 have negative side effects is:

$$
\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X < 2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X = 0) -\mathbb{P}(X = 1)
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = {21\choose 0} p^0(1-p)^{21} \approx 0.86
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = {21\choose 1} p^1(1-p)^{20} \approx 0.12
$$

Thus $$
\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2) \approx 1 - 0.86 - 0.12
$$

Comment: $P(X=0)= .85^{21}=0.032945601$, which is far from what you wrote.

Comment: Your reasoning is hard to follow.  You have been given $p$...it's $.15$ and I am not sure why you would divide that by $21$.

Comment: Because the 15% is on average, at least that's what i thought. But it appears all of you read it differently.

Comment: Right...we expect $15\%$ of the population to have the negative side effects.  Thus, if the population happens to be $21$, we'd expect to find $15\%$ of those people (so about $3.15$ people) to have negative side effects.

Comment: Note: saying that we always expect $.15$ people to have the bad side effects regardless of the population size doesn't make physical sense.

Comment: @lulu ok thanks. i guess i misread the question. much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p = 0.15, (1-p) = 0.85.$

So, the computation is

$$1 ~~- $$

$$\left\{ ~\left[ ~\binom{21}{0} \times (0.15)^0 \times (0.85)^{(21)} ~\right] ~+~ ~\left[ ~\binom{21}{1} \times (0.15)^1 \times (0.85)^{(20)} ~\right] ~\right\}.$$

Comment: much appreciated.